# How to use segues from view controller that has a XIB for it's design?

Tags: ios, swift, xib, xcode-storyboard, unwind-segue

I'm implementing a navigation hierarchy in a storyboard. For part of my navigation, I am drilling down through a tree of data, so I have a couple view controllers in a row with the exact same look but different data management so they need separate controllers. To avoid duplication I did the layout for those views in a XIB, made a VC class for the XIB to handle setting up the views, and then I extend that class for each VC in the storyboard to handle the `UITableViewDataSource` stuff.

Now the navigation is working fine, but I want to have a button on the XIB views that triggers an unwind segue back to the beginning. I have the segues set up with identifiers in the storyboard from my VCs with a XIB layout to the home screen, but no matter what I do, when I call `performSegueWithIdentifier` I always get the `has no segue with identifier` error.

I think what's going on is that everything extra added to the view controller in the storyboard is removed when the XIB is loaded. I found that that was happening with my navigation item in these views and I had to create the navigation item in code since there's no way to add one in a XIB. I suspect something related is happening with the segues, but I can't figure out a workaround. Is it just not possible to have a VC in a storyboard with its layout in a XIB and then perform a segue from it? Is there a programmatic way to do an unwind segue without setting it up in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Unwinding is only available if you are using storyboard. So in your case you have to use `UINavigationController.popViewControllerAnimated` or `UIViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`.

Comment: I know segues are only available in a storyboard, and I _am_ using a storyboard. The issue is that if the view controller in the storyboard has its root view defined by a XIB, the segues don't actually get hooked up. I believe this is just a bug in Interface Builder.